# How to create a one time activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this scenario where I have Three activities lets say A(main Activity) , B , C. Now here is my problem-:

1)- I am using intent to move from A to activity B and then again using intent for activity B to C. I want an implementation where the second time i open the app I want C as my main screen activity i.e, only C must be on the forefront and A and B will not be available anymore. Since A and B are both forms that I have to fill like information form.

I've already implemented on history in manifest file but nothing is happening and I have also used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP , FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_HISTORY still nothing .Now what should I do...
Should I use the shared preferences or is there any flags I can use or is there any way that when I reach to activity C the state saves or something like that.
Please briefly explain your answer with code since I am a rookie.

Comment: `Should I use the shared preferences or is there any flags` yes. There is no way to change launcher activity at runtime, as APK is not modifyable. You should store somewhere information about that it has been already launched for first time, and you need to do different actions.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko and how should I do that

Comment: there arre a lot of ways. For example, in onCreate check if the flag is set. If it is not - set it, and continue with first launch flow. (A->B->C), if it is set - start C, finish A

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko what kind of flag should I set

Comment: any flag you like. For example, some value in shred preferences.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko what do you mean can you show me by an example

Comment: store something in sharedpreferences as flag. Check if it is there - then it's true. Not there - it's false. There is no easier example, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Make your AActivty.java as your default launcher activity

You can set a flag in shared preferences in Activity c onCreate() method

CActivity.java

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("your_app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putBoolean("reached_c", true);
 editor.commit();
```

in onCreate() method of AActivty check for reached_c is true or false and navigate to BActivty or CActivty accordingly

AActivity.java

```
SharedPreferences mPref = getSharedPreferences("your_app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(mPref.getBoolean("reached_c",false)){
    Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this,CActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: @VaibhavBisht please upvote and accept the answer if it worked

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to save your last open activity in SharedPreferences i.e. in `onStart()`
2. Create new activity, make it as default launcher - Read last open activity value from SharedPreferences and start that activity.

Comment: hey is it possible that you can show this by pseudo code or something